# Laravel 5.2 split an application in two parts in order to have authentication and the rest separated

Tags: php, authentication, split, laravel-5

I have an application written in Laravel 5.2, I need to split this app in two parts, app A is responsible of the authentication and app B is responsible for the rest of the app.

Can someone guide me to make it working preserving data for policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a late answer, I solved my problem with a SSO server implementation for the users and use this to log in the main Laravel app.

This can be possible using the Passport and Socialite official packages.